# Wording: A is bounded above by B, independent of C

Tags: proof-writing

Is the sentence

> A is bounded above by B, independent of C.

correct? I am not sure whether it should be *independently* instead of *independent*.

I am sorry for asking this here instead of ell.stackexchange.com, but in my experience I get more competent answers here for questions like this one.

More precisely, $A$ is a function $f_{C}(x)$ and $B$ is a function $g(x)$ and I want to express the mathematical statement
$$
f_{C}(x)\leq g(x) \quad \forall x\forall C
$$
in a part of my manuscript where I would like to avoid this kind of  formalism. The sentence would thus be

> We show that $f_{C}$ is bounded above by $g$, independent of C.

Comment: Either probably works. Could you give a more complete sentence? (It's possible that the answer differs depending on what $A$, $B$ and $C$ are.)

Comment: @Patrick Updated the question